# Returning the "Return Value" not working correct with INSERT in stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value

I'm struggling with this for two days now : I have a simple stored procedure to insert a row into a table and return either 100 if row is already in the table and no insert was done, or 200 if insert was successful.

I keep getting return value of 100 whether row exists and no insert done, or there's no such row and the insert was executed.

The thing is that if I remove the `INSERT` line from the procedure or change it to say `SELECT`, then the return value is correct. I.e. the `INSERT` is the culprit.

This is a .NET C# Windows Application with SQL Server Express.

EDIT : As @tinka said (see his comment below), all I had to do was to comment out the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and everything is cool now.

SO is the BEST!!!

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spTEST]
   @Input_For_SP NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count INT
    DECLARE @ReturnCode INT

    SELECT @Count = COUNT(Test_Name) 
    FROM tblTest 
    WHERE Test_Name = @Input_For_SP

    IF @Count > 0 
        SET @ReturnCode = 100
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        SET @ReturnCode = 200

        INSERT INTO tblTest(Test_Name) VALUES (@Input_For_SP)
    END

    SELECT @ReturnCode AS ReturnValue
END
```

In my Winform I have :

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myTEST4_Result;
        myTEST4_Result = execute_spTEST4(textBox4.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(myTEST4_Result);
    }

    static string execute_spTEST4(string mytextBox4)
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MY_TEST_DATABASE"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTEST", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Input_For_SP", mytextBox4);
        conn.Open();
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                            THIS LINE WAS THE CULPRIT!!!!
        int myReturnedCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        string my_test4_result = myReturnedCode.ToString();
        return (my_test4_result);
    }
```

(I know I can solve it with an OUTPUT Parameter)

What am I missing...?

Comment: comment this line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` from code and test

Comment: @tinka caught it.  You're executing the stored procedure two times.

Comment: @tinka Thank you! That did it. i will edit my question now. Thanks again.

Comment: @gadi try with `RETURN @ReturnCode AS ReturnValue` instead of `SELECT @ReturnCode AS ReturnValue`

Comment: @tinka Changing SELECT to Return throws a syntax error at the AS so I'll leave it with SELECT. Anyhow, your previous idea already solved my problem.

Comment: @tinka If you decide to post an answer just leave a comment to let me know and I will delete the answer I posted.

Comment: @Morpheus no man don't delete the Q please accept the community answer although we all are here for learning. problem should be solved either from comment OR answer :)

Comment: @tinka Sounds good. gadi is the OP so they can accept the answer if they so choose.  As you've stated, I set it to community.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[As stated by @tinka and then edited into the question]*

The reason that the return value always indicated that the rows existed is because the stored procedure was being executed twice

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int myReturnedCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Since there is a return value, we need to keep the call to `ExecuteScalar()`

```
//cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int myReturnedCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```